# Running node.js pm2 remotely using pdsh

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have 4 servers running node.js with the help of pm2 (pm2 start app.js). I would like to restart pm2 on all 4 servers from another server using pdsh however when I run:

```
pdsh -a "/root/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin/pm2 restart 0"
```

it returns:

```
/root/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin/pm2: line 4: exec: : not found
```

I have also done similar to bellow:

```
pdsh -a "sh /etc/profile && sh ~/.bash_profile && /root/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin/pm2 restart 0"
```

and same error occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run pm2 directly from the `node` path. It appears that `pdsh` can't load `nvm`

If you've installed it from `nvm` it should be something like that:

```
~/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin/node
```

Pm2 on the other hand should be in the node_modules directory:

```
~/.nvm/v0.10.30/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
```

So if we combine all this it becomes:

```
/root/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin/node /root/.nvm/v0.10.30/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 restart 0
```